# Make: error compiling .o

Tags: makefile

My makefile below works after I clean and remove all object files, however if I edit a source file and then run make again, it outputs the error below. I believe this is coming from the lines:

```
 %.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I thought I had a basic grasp of automatic variables, but something isn't right.

Makefile:

```
all: main

CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall  `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -I /usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/ 
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
INCLUDE = -I /usr/local/include/libfreenect
FREE_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lfreenect

main: device.cpp cups.cpp main.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $? -o $@ $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) 

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

Output from make:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
$(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $? -o $@ $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS)
```

you use `$?`, which means only the *updated* dependencies will be used in the command.  (You should be seeing this in the command.)

Use `$+` instead.  (See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).)

*(PS: This is one half of the answer; the other half is Sagar Sakre's advice.)*

Comment: It's not true that `$?` means _only one of the dependencies will be used_.  `$?` means that only UPDATED prerequisites will be used; any prerequisites that are not updated will not be there.  This is why it works if you start from a clean directory, because all the prerequisites don't exist so all will be remade, so all will appear in the `$?` variable.  When you only remake one file (or two files or whatever), only those prerequisites appear in `$?`.  That's never what you want for linking.

Comment: BTW, automatic variables are described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

Comment: Whoops - thanks for the correction. I have incorporated your remarks into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`main` taget should depend on `.o` files instead of `.cpp`

change

```
main: device.cpp cups.cpp main.cpp
```

to

```
main: device.o cups.o main.o
```

everything should work fine

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same error if I make, edit, make.